# Synomymize energy with bioenergetics

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can [energy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy) be made a synonym of [bioenergetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioenergetics).

The former is a broad term and makes sense in biology only in the case of bioenergetics. Ironically the former **had** more tagged posts (which I retagged to bioenergetics)
Though *energy* is a more popular term, it is too broad and *bionergetics* is the more appropriate for this site.

Comment: Could you make a suggestion on which type of questions should be tagged with bioenergetics? The border of the topic is rather fuzzy as a lot of biological processes are in the end about energy.

Comment: @MadScientist All questions related to metabolic energy production/consumption should be tagged as bioenergetics. I don't think we talk about any other forms of energy here. I was checking out tag wikis and then I wondered what should I write about energy: listing types of energy and talking about laws of thermodynamics would be physics*ish*. Bioenergetics on the other hand is strictly about the energy required to sustain life and can be provided an apt definition.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Please include [tag:energy-metabolism] in this proposal.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly agree; but partly not.

Not agree in part:

[Bioenergetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioenergetics) means how the energy is dealt in living systems.

But there could be some other situations where, within biology stack exchange we may have to encounter questions about energy, but not exactly about energy-flow through biological system, but rather about [environment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environment), [global-warming](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-warming), etc. to indicate energy flow in the abiotic part of environment.

So, tag [bioenergetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioenergetics) could be improper for such situation.

.........................................................

- Agree, (found helpful, but suggesting some-other solution) in the part:

On the other hand, the question points a fact that; in most cases, questions tagged with [energy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy) indicates energy-flow through biological system; so in that cases, tag [energy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy) is same as [bioenergetics].

More over, there are questions tagged with both [energy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy) and [bioenergetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioenergetics) at the same time. A simple search in the BioSE (main site) question search box as `[bioenergetics], [energy]` displays them. Such as [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59413/how-do-plants-store-energy-by-potassium-battery), [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36239/which-step-in-endocytosis-requires-atp), [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/53959/what-does-energy-transfer-in-cells-mean) and [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44346/mechanism-behind-energy-generation).

In such cases where we are telling specifically about energy through biological system; we could use only the tag [bioenergetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioenergetics), and in cases where we are talking about energy in abiotic environment; or about something generally applicable for both living and non-living systems; we could suggest more non-specific tag [energy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy)